# Help proving an inequality

Tags: inequality

I need to prove this inequality:

$$\bigg(\frac{1}{1+n}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{m}}+\bigg(\frac{1}{1+m}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}  \geq 1$$

I tried ^${nm}$ then make the LCD and because $n$ and $m $ and natural, then it must be positive so it equals to it's absolute value and finally use the triangle inequality.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please indicate what restrictions there are on $n$ and $m$. If $n=m=\frac12$ then the left hand side becomes $$2\times\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac12}\right)^2=2\times\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2=2\times\frac49=\frac89$$

Comment: n and m are natural numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\bigg(\frac{1}{1+n}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{m}}+\bigg(\frac{1}{1+m}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}  \geq \frac{1}{1+\frac{n}{m}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{m}{n}}=1$$

Comment: You might want to justify that inequality, since it is not at all obvious.

Comment: @SBareS I think it's true since for $x\in[0,1]$ and $n\geq1$, $$(1+n)^x\le1+nx$$

Comment: Got it, thanks guys